# Pandas: Return name of a column if there is a match in the row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with pandas in Python. I'm trying to return the name of a column when a cell of a row matches with another cell in the same row. This is an example:

```
     City 1    City 2  City 3 City 4       1       2         3      4     5
0  New York    London   Paris  Tokyo  London   Tokyo  New York  Paris   X  
1     Paris  New York  London  Tokyo   Tokyo  London  New York  Paris   X
```

I'm looking for the next coincidence to the column City 1 (the value is New York). In the first row this match is in the column named '3'. Then, I would like in the column 5, where X is it should appear '3' because 'New York' appears in the column '3'. The same for next one... I would look for the match with City 1 (Paris) and then the column 5 should show '4' because Paris is in that column.

I hope I've explained properly. Do you have any suggestion about how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean first match? Because Paris, Tokyo, London also matcing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are checking the next occurance of City 1

```py
df[5] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x == x['City 1']].index[-1], axis = 1)
```

```
    City 1  City 2  City 3  City 4  1   2   3   4   5
0   New York    London  Paris   Tokyo   London  Tokyo   New York    Paris   3
1   Paris   New York    London  Tokyo   Tokyo   London  New York    Paris   4
```

Comment: I've tried to appy this solution for a different df and in the column '5' it doesn't show correctly the number of the match, but displays the equivalent to text "City 1". How could I fix it?

Comment: That means it doesn't have a match